# That's a misunderstanding

Tags: nouns, gerunds

> That's a misunderstanding.

Why do you say "a misunderstanding", instead of that's misunderstanding?

Why do  you need an article for this gerund?

Comment: It's not a gerund; it's a noun that is usually non-count, but can be count as well.

Answer (score 6):

***[Misunderstanding](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/misunderstanding)***  is a noun both countable and uncountable:

> - ***[ C or U ] an occasion when someone does not understand something correctly:***
>
>   - There must be ***some misunderstanding***. I never asked for these chairs to be delivered.
>   - His ridiculous comments showed ***a complete misunderstanding*** of the situation.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Other usage examples:

> - If there is any misunderstanding and discord between you and Mary, I can't blame her for it at a all.
> - There are materials for misunderstanding here.
> - "I am very, very grateful to you," she said in French, "but I hope it was all a misunderstanding and that no one is to blame for it."

Comment: -1 What is the source of these "other usage examples"?   (If they're on Cambridge, they are not on the linked page on mobile view.)

Answer (score 3):

Words  that end in *-ing* are not  always  gerunds or *-ing forms* of verbs. For example,

**building** is very often used as a noun

> That's a building you don't want to enter.

Yet, *building* can be a gerund:

> **Building** a building is hard work.

The bolded *building* is a gerund. The *building*  after the indefinite article is a count noun that is not considered a gerund.

The same applies to *misunderstanding*. It is a common noun, just like *building*. And that's how it is used in the sentence you ask about.

But it can be a gerund:

> Misunderstanding you makes me ill.

---

(Historically, *building* and similar words used as common nouns may have originated as gerunds, but I'm not sure.)