# A great rattling of coaches in the streets

Tags: grammar

When do you use "a rattling" instead of plain rattling?

Is a rattling different from just rattling, like crossing and a crossing?

Comment: Can you give an example of where you saw "a rattling"? It'll help us determine why that person used it

Comment: This is from Moby Dick: ">And it was so light too; the sun shining in at the window, and a great rattling of coaches in the streets, and the sound of gay voices all over the house."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [That's a misunderstanding](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103602/thats-a-misunderstanding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is extraordinarily subtle - to me, saying that there was "a rattling" gives an impression of a single source or at least uniformity of the type of rattling, whereas simply "there was rattling" may suggest a less specific source and perhaps more diffuse effect.

But it's a nuance and depends on context. In the cited example from Moby Dick...

> And it was so light too; the sun shining in at the window, and a great
> rattling of coaches in the streets, and the sound of gay voices all
> over the house.

... we might ask what the effect would be if Melville had replaced "a great rattling" with simply "great rattling." The answer is: very little, if any. Stylistically, given the use of an adjective ("great"), "great rattling" sounds better to me with an article before it; i.e., either "a great rattling" or "the great rattling" would sound better in this particular case than just "great rattling," but any would of these three options would work grammatically and the meaning wouldn't really differ.

In any case, as you by now see, we don't have any real substantial distinction here on the order of "crossing" (the action) vs. "a crossing" (the physical/geographical thing).

Comment: Thank you greatly. Your explanation was exquisite, if I said it correctly.